# pointer-event:none that dosen't disables my label for checkbox toggle button

Tags: css, angular, typescript

I am trying to disable my full form but when I add pointer-event:none that doesn't disable my toggle buttons of checkbox in angular I am using ngClass I have tried

```
    .disabled {
        pointer-events: none;
        opacity: 0.7;
    }
```

and in HTML i am using

```
<form [ngClass]="{'disabled': creationStatus == 'Step 1 Form Submitted'}">
```

asdfasdf